# Калькулятор через Switch и возникла ошибка

Tags: c++11

Объясните в чем я ошибся

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

int main(){
int a;
int b;
int choice;
cout << "напишите первое число: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "напишите второе число: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Что хотите сделать: \n";
cout << "1. Сложение ( + )\n";
cout << "2. Вычитание ( - )\n";
cout << "3. Умножение ( * )\n";
cout << "4. Деление ( % )\n";
switch(choice){
    case 1:
        cout << (a + b);
    break;
    case 2:
        cout << (a - b);
    break;
    case 3:
        cout << (a * b);
    break;
    case 4:
        cout << (a % b);
    break;
    default:
        cout << "Выбрано неверное действие!";
        break;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что тут раскрывать? Вы просто не читаете `choice` (кстати, думаю, что компилятор вас предупредил об использовании неинициализированной переменной), вот и все.